# Can't convert string to date in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I want to convert a string into a date. Here's the code:

```
cumple = input('When is your birthday? ')
formato = '%d/%m/%Y'
cumpleFecha = datetime.datetime.strptime(cumple, formato)
print('Your birthday is ' + cumpleFecha)
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'datetime.datetime' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because a `datetime` object is not a string, you cannot just concatenate (using `+`) to a string.

Remove the `+`, and pass in the `datetime` object as a separate argument:

```
print('Your birthday is', cumpleFecha)
```

This leaves conversion to a string to the `print()` function.

Or convert it to a string explicitly:

```
print('Your birthday is ' + str(cumpleFecha))
```

or

```
print('Your birthday is ' + cumpleFecha.strftime('%d %B %Y')
```

Comment: `print('Your birthday is {:%d %B %Y}'.format(cumpleFecha))`. Or after PEP-498: `print(f'Your birthday is {cumpleFecha:%d %B %Y}')`